# SQL Error: value too long for type character(3)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm getting this error:

> psql:prep6_queries.txt:2: ERROR:  value too long for type character(3)
>
> psql:prep6_queries.txt:5: ERROR:  value too long for type character(3)
>
> psql:prep6_queries.txt:8: ERROR:  value too long for type character(3)
>
> INSERT 0 1
>
> INSERT 0 1
>
> psql:prep6_queries.txt:27: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VALUES"
>       LINE 2: VALUES ('BOR', 'Klingon', NULL, NULL);
>
> ^

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO Country(code, name, continent, population)
VALUES ('Borduria', 'BOR', 'Pangaea', 1000);

INSERT INTO country(code, name, continent, population)
VALUES ('Cagliostro', 'CAG', 'Pangaea', 250);

INSERT INTO country(code, name, continent, population)
VALUES ('Qumar', 'MAR', 'Pangaea', 3380);

INSERT INTO countrylanguage(countrycode, countrylanguage, isofficial, percentage)
VALUES ('BOR', 'English', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO countrylanguage(countrycode, countrylanguage, isofficial, percentage)
VALUES ('BOR', 'Italian', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO countrylanguage(countrycode, countrylanguage, isofficial, percentag
VALUES  ('BOR', 'Klingon', NULL, NULL);

DELETE FROM country
WHERE population < 300;

UPDATE country
SET continent = 'Luna'
WHERE name = 'Borduria' and code = 'BOR';
INSERT INTO Country(code, name, continent, population)
VALUES ('Borduria', 'BOR', 'Pangaea', 1000);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I don't understand the errors it gives me. Is it because of the country code? The country code is 3 characters long. Am I using the wrong quotation marks? Any advice?

Comment: Please provide us the definition of tables.

Answer (score 3):

There is an obvious syntax error here:

```
INSERT INTO countrylanguage(countrycode, countrylanguage, isofficial, percentag
--                                                                             ^^^^
--                                                                             here
VALUES  ('BOR', 'Klingon', NULL, NULL);
```

A closing parenthesis and a `e` are missing. To fix:

```
INSERT INTO countrylanguage(countrycode, countrylanguage, isofficial, percentage)
VALUES  ('BOR', 'Klingon', NULL, NULL);
```

---

Following your comment:

```
INSERT INTO Country(code, name, continent, population)
VALUES ('Borduria', 'BOR', 'Pangaea', 1000);
--      ^^^^^       ^^^^^
--      code?       name?
```

Should probably be:

```
INSERT INTO Country(name, code, continent, population)
VALUES ('Borduria', 'BOR', 'Pangaea', 1000);
```

Comment: I doubt it's the *same* one, please edit your question, add the fixed sql you use and your tables structure. Note that: Country code and name seems reversed in you 3st statements, see my edit